# Yii2 Invalid Call: Setting read-only property

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a `Post` model that has a many-many relationship with `Tags`.

Defined in Post model:

```
public function getTags(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tags::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
        ->viaTable('post_tags', ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

But `Post::tags` is read-only. So when I try to set them in the Controller, I get an error:

> Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException
>
> Setting read-only property: app\models\Post::tags

The controller is using load to set all the properties:

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $P = new Post();
    if( Yii::$app->request->post() ){
        $P->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $P->save();
        return $this->redirect('/posts');
    }
    return $this->render('create', ['model'=>$P]);
}
```

The input field in the view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tags')->textInput(['value'=>$model->stringTags()]) ?>
```

Why is `Post::tags` read-only? And whats the proper way to set a model relationship?

Comment: please show your controller code

Comment: Added that and the relevant part of the view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here `tags`

```
public function getTags(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tags::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
        ->viaTable('post_tags', ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

is a relation name and returns the object and is not just a attribute or database column.

You cannot use it with `textInput()` like other attribute for eg `email`, `first_name`.

So you are given error of `Setting read-only property`.

In order to remove this error, you need to create new attrbute or property to model like below

```
class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecordsd
{
    public $tg;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ...
            ['tg', 'string', 'required'],
        ];
    }
    // ...
```

**In view file**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tg')->textInput(['value'=>$model->stringTags()]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting read-only property: app\models\Post::tags because you need add in your model property $tags:

```
public $tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, setting a relation is not required. But if you need it:

```
php composer.phar require la-haute-societe/yii2-save-relations-behavior "*"
```

Model

```
class Post extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'saveRelations' => [
                'class' => SaveRelationsBehavior::class,
                'relations' => [
                    'author',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Now this code will not cause errors `Setting read-only property` =)

```
$post->author = Author::findOne(2);
```

In addition, module [yii2-save-relations-behavior](https://github.com/la-haute-societe/yii2-save-relations-behavior) help save easier `hasMany` relations